# Not able to call a shell variable as other variable within the script

Tags: python, bash, shell, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

in order to parse yaml file, we were using the solution provided [here](https://github.com/mrbaseman/parse_yaml) and which is working expected for us to generate the variables in the key value pairs of yaml.

The script part which I tried is as below

```
#!/bin/bash
source parse_yaml.sh
eval $(parse_yaml sample2.yaml policy)

echo ".............Eval Result..............................."
for f in $policy_ ; do eval echo \$f \$${f}_ ; done
echo "............Eval Result................................"

for f in $policy_ ; do
  if [[ $(eval echo \$${f}_name) == "ipfilter" ]]; then
    echo " given policy name is ipfilter "
    for g in $(eval echo \$${f}_session_); do
      if [[ $(eval echo \$${g}) == "inbound" ]]; then
      echo "add the add above Ipfilter string to the inbound session of xml"
      fi
      if [[ $(eval echo \$${g}) == "outbound" ]]; then
      echo "add the add above Ipfilter string to the outbound session of xml"
      fi
      if [[ $(eval echo \$${g}) == "backend" ]]; then
      echo "add the add above Ipfilter string to the backend session of xml"
      fi
    done
    for h in $(eval echo \$${f}_api_); do
      echo "decided the scope of Ipfilter policy as $(eval echo \$${h})"
    done
    for i in $(eval echo \$${f}_operations_); do
      echo "decided the scope of Ipfilter policy as $(eval echo \$${i})"
    done
  fi
done
```

In our scenario below, the policy list can be n numbers and in each policies there can be multiple sessions and operations also can be list . So our requirement is to create custom policy file related to each of these properties of each policy and apply in its scope.

################  Policy  ################

````
- name: policy1
  session:
     - inbound
     - backend
  scope: api
  apiname:
  customvalue1: xxxxx
  customvalue2: xxxxx


- name: policyB
  scope: operation
  operation:
      - operation1
      - operation2
  session:
     - inbound
     - backend
  customvalue3: xxxxx
  customvalue4: xxxxx

etc.....................................

```
````

in the above scenario, we are not able to dynamically loop the policies properties such as session value and operation value to add condition based on them.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend. Start by fixing everything it identifies, before doing anything else -- I'd suggest deleting the question, then undeleting it when you have new, shellcheck-clean code.

Comment: Also, if you're going to use the bash tag, make sure the active shell _really is_ bash. Bash has a bunch of [shiny modern features](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) that mean you don't need `eval` for indirect assignment or expansion, so you need a _very_ different answer between bash or sh. (`eval` [causes major security and correctness issues](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) when used incautiously, and what you have right now is very much incautious; it would be easier to switch to newer, bash-native constructs than to make the eval usage safe).

Comment: (One red flag that sticks out -- any library that tells you you're supposed to use it as `eval $(parse_yaml ...)` and not `eval "$(parse_yaml ...)"` is written by someone who doesn't know what they're doing, and is thus presumptively dangerous; you don't want substrings that look like glob characters to be expanded by filesystem contents before `eval` glues its arguments back together with spaces and parses the result of that operation as code; that whole split/glob/glue chain of operations is avoided by proper use of syntactic quotes).

Comment: ...personally, I'd use a YAML processor with the ability to perform shell-safe escaping here. That's easy to do in Python with any YAML library you choose and the `shlex.quote()` standard-library tool, or in JQ (if you either get from YAML to JSON or use a wrapper that does that conversion for you) with its `@sh` builtin.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can u help me here with any reference to python , where i can solve this.

Comment: That's not really a specific enough question to be answerable. [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) and [shlex.quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html#shlex.quote) are the only two things you need to be aware of other than just general-purpose familiarity with the Python language.